# Disable Media On Twitter Timeline Embed

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, twitter

I am trying to disable some things on the Twitter embed. I tried using jQuery to no avail. Because of container restrictions, I need to limit the content that the Twitter feed displays. One thing I am trying to to remove media. I tried this using a variety of selectors. For simplicity sake I will include just one selector which wraps the part of the Twitter feed I am trying to hide.

I originally tried to put the jQuery in a separate file but this example show it inline as I thought it might read it if it loads after (Spoiler Alert: it doesn't). I also tried including !important but that didn't work so I also removed it for now.

[CodePen](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/qXmwwW)

I don't want to define the height and width because the feed will be responsive. Any and all help is appreciated.

```
<a class="twitter-timeline" data-tweet-limit="1" data-link-color="#ff3300" href="https://twitter.com/Google" data-width="100%" style="min-width:50px; max-width:100%;" data-chrome="nofooter noheader noborders"></a> <script async src="//platform.twitter.com/widgets.js" charset="utf-8">jQuery('.MediaCard').css('display', 'none');</script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately you **can't do this**, as Twitter is on a different domain to you. To manipulate `<iframe>` content, the iframe needs to be on the same domain,
 and obey the [**Same Origin Policy**](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same_origin_policy). Because Twitter is **not** the same domain, it falls victim to [**CORS**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Access_control_CORS) (Cross-origin Resource Sharing).

Assuming that it was on the **same** domain to you, you would be able to hide any images on the embedded timeline with:

`$("#twitter-widget-0").contents().find(img).hide();`

Note that like jQuery, CSS is also unable to access the `<iframe>` content from another domain; you're limited to only targeting the `<iframe>` element directly.

Though it's probably not what you want to hear, I hope this helps :)